# Is there any way to use Firebase hosting/platform for an ACTUAL working website written in ejs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, ejs

So I know perfectly well how to use Firebase hosting and platform for a website code file such as index.html or app.js(in this case, use Cloud Functions). But what about a website that has zero code in html but only ejs code  ? I tried running Firebase for it and it didn't work because Firebase could not find any index.html file sitting in Public folder because there was no html file to begin with and then when Firebase searched for app.js file in functions folder, it failed as well because there was no file with the extension ".js". So is there no way to run  a website purely written in an ejs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think EJS is supported in Firebase hosting. You'd have to host your own Express site elsewhere